# Splitting GET string

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all, explode, preg-split

I need to split my GET string into some array. The string looks like this:

```
ident[0]=<IDENT_0>&value[0]=<VALUE_0>&version[0]=<VERSION_0>&....&ident[N]=<IDENT_N>&value[N]=<VALUE_N>&version[N]=<VERSION_N>
```

So, I need to split this string by every third ampersand character, like this:

```
ident[0]=<IDENT_0>&value[0]=<VALUE_0>&version[0]=<VERSION_0>
ident[1]=<IDENT_1>&value[1]=<VALUE_1>&version[1]=<VERSION_1> and so on...
```

How can I do it? What regular expression should I use? Or is here some better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *preg_split* with this pattern: `&(?=ident)`

```
$result = preg_split('~&(?=ident)~', $yourstring);
```

regex detail: `&(?=ident)` means *`&` followed by `ident`*

`(?=..)` is a lookahead assertion that performs only a check but match nothing.

Or using *preg_match_all*:

```
preg_match_all('~(?<=^|&)[^&]+&[^&]+&[^&]+(?=&|$)~', $yourstring, &matches);
$result = $matches[0];
```

pattern detail: `(?<=..)` is a lookbehind assertion

`(?<=^|&)` means *preceded by the begining of the string `^` or an ampersand*.
`[^&]+` means *all characters except the ampersand one or more times*.
`(?=&|$)` means *followed by an ampersand or the end of the string `$`*.

Or you can use *explode*, and then a *for* loop:

```
$items = explode('&', $yourstring);
for ( $i=0; $i<sizeof($items); $i += 3 ) {
    $result[] = implode('&', array_slice($items, $i, 3));
}
```

Comment: can't understand reg. expression You wrote '~&(?=ident)~' What does it mean ? I need splitting by every third ampersand...

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way (assuming this is data being sent to your PHP page, not some other thing you're dealing with).

PHP provides a "magic" array called [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) which already has the values parsed out for you.

For example:

```
one=1&two=2&three=3
```

Would result in this array:

```
Array ( [one] => 1 [two] => 2 [three] => 3 )
```

So you could access the variables like so:

```
$oneValue = $_GET['one'];  // answer is 1
$twoValue = $_GET['two'];  // and so on
```

If you provide array indexes, which your example does, it'll sort those out for you as well. So, to use your example above `$_GET` would look like:

```
Array
(
    [ident] => Array
        (
            [0] => <IDENT_0>
            [N] => <IDENT_N>
        )

    [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => <VALUE_0>
            [N] => <VALUE_N>
        )

    [version] => Array
        (
            [0] => <VERSION_0>
            [N] => <VERSION_N>
        )
)
```

I'd assume your `N` keys will actually be numbers, so you'll be able to look them up like so:

```
$_GET['ident'][0]     // =>   <IDENT_0>
$_GET['value'][0]     // =>   <VALUE_0>
$_GET['version'][0]   // =>   <VERSION_0>
```

You could loop across them all or whatever, and you will never have to worry about splitting them all out yourself.

Hope it helps you.